# Rails 3.1 authenticity_token + uploadify

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, uploadify, authenticity-token

I am trying to use Uploadify with my Rails 3.1 app, i've went through all the steps (middleware, initializers, config ...etc) and i think they are all working good but for one thing, my authenticity token is being "evaluated" somewhere in the process and the (+) plus signs are then turned into spaces! .. my original token is

```
<meta content="GS19lVJNr+/6ghijiM/hNZbo9a89I64nn1Sg+1zbqC8=" name="csrf-token" />
```

while the one that i see on the console is

```
"authenticity_token"=>"GS19lVJNr /6ghijiM/hNZbo9a89I64nn1Sg 1zbqC8="
```

and this of course results in "Cant' verify authenticity token" error and then the request is redirected to elsewhere.

any ideas on that? thank you.

Comment: did you ever fix the issue? I'm running into the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do you encode it?

If you're using something like `encodeURIComponent` try it like so:

```
encodeURI(encodeURIComponent(token))
```

or just try to encode/decode the token right in the firebug/chrome tools to see what's happening

EDIT

that's weird. Can you please show the entire scriptData you're sending?

Comment: Yes thank you now the tokens are identical but the problem remains! any tips on where should i look?

Answer (score 0):

...had the same problem in Rails 3.2.9 but in my case the reason was that I was using [this middleware](http://erniemiller.org/2010/07/09/uploadify-and-rails-3/) which is ment for Rails 3.0 , once I removed it it was working